# Add Leading Zeros to Strings in Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, string, pandas

I have a pandas data frame where the first 3 columns are strings:

```
         ID        text1    text 2
0       2345656     blah      blah
1          3456     blah      blah
2        541304     blah      blah        
3        201306       hi      blah        
4   12313201308    hello      blah
```

I want to add leading zeros to the ID:

```
                ID    text1    text 2
0  000000002345656     blah      blah
1  000000000003456     blah      blah
2  000000000541304     blah      blah        
3  000000000201306       hi      blah        
4  000012313201308    hello      blah
```

I have tried:

```
df['ID'] = df.ID.zfill(15)
df['ID'] = '{0:0>15}'.format(df['ID'])
```

Comment: can you please explain how ```'{0:0>15}'.format(df['ID'])``` works.

Answer (score 121, accepted):

Try:

```
df['ID'] = df['ID'].apply(lambda x: '{0:0>15}'.format(x))
```

or even

```
df['ID'] = df['ID'].apply(lambda x: x.zfill(15))
```

Comment: No need for the `lambda` on the first one: `apply('{:0>15}'.format)` should work too.

Comment: @DSM Nice. Did not know that.

Comment: It can be achieved with single line while initialization, see my answer below.

Comment: @Rohit how would the code change if the string had decimals or letters in it? i.e. what is required for converting `2.0a` to `02.0a` using a `lambda x: x.zfill(2)`?

Comment: Can you explain why you use 15 , what is the significance of the number, what if I only want to add one `0`?

Comment: Hi @MurtazaHaji 15 is the desired total length of the string

Answer (score 151):

`str` attribute contains most of the methods in string.

```
df['ID'] = df['ID'].str.zfill(15)
```

See more: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/text.html

Comment: added df['ID'] = df['ID'].astype(str) to handle when ID is numeric, the run df['ID'] = df['ID'].str.zfill(15)

Comment: For a more general and customizable solution, one can use [`str.pad`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.pad.html); you can have a look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64806147/7465462)

Comment: I get n error running this that int doesn't have attribute string.

Answer (score 19):

It can be achieved with a single line while initialization. Just use [converters](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html) argument.

```
df = pd.read_excel('filename.xlsx', converters={'ID': '{:0>15}'.format})
```

so you'll reduce the code length by half :)

PS: [read_csv](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_excel.html) have this argument as well.

Answer (score 19):

With Python 3.6+, you can also use f-strings:

```
df['ID'] = df['ID'].map(lambda x: f'{x:0>15}')
```

Performance is comparable or slightly worse versus `df['ID'].map('{:0>15}'.format)`. On the other hand, f-strings permit more complex output, and you can use them more efficiently via a list comprehension.

#### Performance benchmarking

```
# Python 3.6.0, Pandas 0.19.2

df = pd.concat([df]*1000)

%timeit df['ID'].map('{:0>15}'.format)                  # 4.06 ms per loop
%timeit df['ID'].map(lambda x: f'{x:0>15}')             # 5.46 ms per loop
%timeit df['ID'].astype(str).str.zfill(15)              # 18.6 ms per loop

%timeit list(map('{:0>15}'.format, df['ID'].values))    # 7.91 ms per loop
%timeit ['{:0>15}'.format(x) for x in df['ID'].values]  # 7.63 ms per loop
%timeit [f'{x:0>15}' for x in df['ID'].values]          # 4.87 ms per loop
%timeit [str(x).zfill(15) for x in df['ID'].values]     # 21.2 ms per loop

# check results are the same
x = df['ID'].map('{:0>15}'.format)
y = df['ID'].map(lambda x: f'{x:0>15}')
z = df['ID'].astype(str).str.zfill(15)

assert (x == y).all() and (x == z).all()
```

Comment: tried this with a 6gb file, works way faster than other methods, also more efficient. thanks @jpp

Comment: You can even use `.map` instead of `.apply`

Comment: @user32185, I *believe* they are interchangeable here and perform equally. Do you have a reason to think otherwise?

Comment: In some examples it's faster. Try `df['text1'].map('{:015}'.format)`.

Comment: @user32185, Thank you, I see a very marginal improvement changing `apply` vs `map`, I'm not sure if that's setup dependent. I've updated timings and advice in my answer as `str.format` without `lambda` seems to win.

Comment: It seems to me that you replaced all `.apply`s with `.map`s. I think it will be better have all the options.

Comment: @user32185, I'd rather focus on string manipulation functions. Your question is another question, but a good one *if you see a big difference* (which I don't). If you think it's important, you can [ask as a new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) so we have a canonical to point to with a reasoning.

Comment: I don't have any question. I suggested you a faster method and you could just edit and add to your answer. You first claimed it was not faster, then said it's just marginally faster and finally replaced your original solution with the one I suggested.

Comment: @user32185, I'm saying it's irrelevant (a few microseconds prove little). I just happened to use `map` last (by chance, not by intention). To me, I can use either without changing the purpose or impact. If you think it *is* relevant, then I suggest you point to some evidence or reasoning.

Answer (score 16):

If you are encountering the error:

Pandas error: Can only use .str accessor with string values, which use np.object_ dtype in pandas

```
df['ID'] = df['ID'].astype(str).str.zfill(15)
```

Comment: Error seems to have been updated, but this solution still works. AttributeError: Can only use .str accessor with string values!. Did you mean: 'std'?

Answer (score 12):

If you want a more customizable solution to this problem, you can try [`pandas.Series.str.pad`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.pad.html#pandas.Series.str.pad)

```
df['ID'] = df['ID'].astype(str).str.pad(15, side='left', fillchar='0')
```

`str.zfill(n)` is a special case equivalent to `str.pad(n, side='left', fillchar='0')`

Answer (score 2):

**ADD Leading Zeros to the Numeric Column in pandas:**

```
df['ID']=df['ID'].apply(lambda x: '{0:0>15}'.format(x))
```

**ADD Leading Zeros to the character column in pandas:**

***Method1:using Zfill***

```
df['ID'] = df['ID'].str.zfill(15)
```

***Method2:using rjust() function***

```
df['ID']=df['ID'].str.rjust(15, "0")
```

Source : https://www.datasciencemadesimple.com/add-leading-preceding-zeros-python/

Answer (score 1):

[rjust](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.rjust.html) worked for me:

```
df['ID']= df['ID'].str.rjust(15,'0')
```