# How to keep leading 0 when export pandas dataframe to csv?

Tags: python, r

I am exporting the data frame below to csv file in Python. The leading 0s are removed in the csv file.

```
      Name         ID
0     Bob          0245
1     Tina         2G5B
```

Both Name and ID values are strings in my pandas df.

I have no problem when re-opening the pandas df in Python with leading 0s after the df is saved by specifying `dtype = 'str'` in `pd.read_csv`.

However, I would like to open it in R using the read.csv command, the leading 0s will disappear.

If there is a way that I can save the csvs in Python with leading 0s showing up in the csv file. This problem could be solved.

Please advice.

Thanks!

Comment: This might help [How to save a CSV from dataframe, to keep zeros left in column with numbers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48903008/how-to-save-a-csv-from-dataframe-to-keep-zeros-left-in-column-with-numbers).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we are. using `R`, then also use the `colClasses` argument from `read.csv` to read it as `character` else, otherwise it would automatically pick up the `type` of the columns from the values and read it as numeric

```
df1 <- read.csv("file.csv", colClasses = "character")
```

Comment: Thanks guys for your answer! I tried specifying colClasses = "character" in read.csv command when opening it in R. However, the df in R still does not have leading 0s for the values that should have. Is this because there is no leading 0s in the csv saved from Python, and R does not recognize it?

Comment: And in ID column, I have both character and numeric values. They are strings when save them in csv in Python.

Comment: @MAMS Probably, when you saved the .csv, it may not have.  Please check that file

Comment: @MAMS If the column contains at least a string, it will be by default read as character (also check `stringsAsFactors` in `read.csv`

Comment: @akrun Yes, the leading 0s are in pandas df in python, but not in the csv saved. Is there a way to keep those 0s in the csv when export using to_csv command?

Comment: I reckon this is not `R`'s problem. As indicated in the OP, the `csvs` don't have them.

Comment: @MAMS. You can check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17092671/python-pandas-output-dataframe-to-csv-with-integers)

Comment: @deepseefan. OP didn't show the `read.csv` code.  So, I don't know whether he included `colClasses` or not

Comment: @akrun I was recounting the last sentences of the OP where it says `... that I can save the csvs in Python with leading 0s showing up ..`.

Comment: Thanks for your advice guys. Adding a sep argument in to_csv command solved my problem!