# Python save CSV without changing ID to an integer

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have a df *in Python* with an ID column - those IDs can be a mix of numbers and letters, or solely numbers. Eg:

| ID |
| --- |
| 00028D9D1 |
| 00027B98F |
| 000275457 |

When I save this df out, using pandas `to_csv` I see in the resulting csv file when I share with others (or open up myself), I see the IDs that contain letters are maintained as is / treated as text, but the IDs that are solely numbers are treated as integers, and automatically formatted that way. For example, I would see this in my csv file after saving:

| ID |
| --- |
| 00028D9D1 |
| 00027B98F |
| 275457 |

Is there any way to disable this automatic treatment of integers, leading to different formatting? The `dtype` of this column does say it is an `object` so I assumed it would save in the same format for all values.

Comment: This was answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23836277/add-leading-zeros-to-strings-in-pandas-dataframe

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to save a CSV from dataframe, to keep zeros left in column with numbers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48903008/how-to-save-a-csv-from-dataframe-to-keep-zeros-left-in-column-with-numbers)

Comment: Are you opening this in Excel? Note that Excel is pretty terrible with CSVs. What do you see in a different text editor such as Notepad(++)?

Comment: I'd expect `object` to work as a placeholder here.

Answer (score 0):

According to [RFC 4180](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc4180), CSV files do not contain any type information, so it is solely the responsibility of the application to correctly interpret the contents of the file. From what I read in your question,

> I have a df in Python with an ID column - those IDs can be a mix of numbers and letters, or solely numbers.

and as far as I interpret your *specification*, it you'll have something like this:

**input.csv**

```
ID
00028D9D1
00027B98F
000275457
```

**script**

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('input.csv')
print(df)
print(df['ID'].dtype)
df.to_csv('output.csv', index=False)
```

**console output**

```
          ID
0  00028D9D1
1  00027B98F
2  000275457
object
```

**output.csv**

```
ID
00028D9D1
00027B98F
000275457
```

In other words, use the right tool to "open up" the CSV file you create.

As I observe on Windows, spreadsheet applications like *Excel* or *Open/Libre office* register themselves with the `.csv` file extension, so just *opening* a CSV will lead to a very generic interpretation of data: cells that can be converted into a number without errors are treated as integer cells, regardless of their column.

One application that lets you view the actual contents of a text file is [Windows Notepad](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Notepad), for example, but as a programmer you probably know better alternatives.